# Where get content in fragment?

Tags: java, android

Here is my fragment

```
public class Top_Tab1 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.top_tab_1,container,false);
    Typeface type_thin = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    return v;   
}
```

**getAssets()** get me an error: **Cannot resolve method**. I think i need a content here. Where can I get It?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Context`, `getActivity()` will get you one.

```
getActivity().getAssets()
```

but you'll have to move this to `onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle)`.

Comment: It's getting me this: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: You may have to move that to onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) although the error message seems weird. How do you create the fragment?